# Unable to Update data to database, Even if the code is working fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This Is the Code i wrote. Everything is working Fine as viewed in Quick Watch, But the Database is not getting updated.

IN updatedata.aspx.cs

```
using (var dc = new TrainingEntities())
      {
        var oldData = dc.tr_schools.ToList();
        var newData = oldData.Select(o => new tr_schools()
          {
            banner = o.banner,
            imageOff = o.imageOff,
            imageOn = o.imageOn,
            name = o.name,
            schoolUID = o.schoolUID,
            sequence = o.sequence,
            title = o.title,
            tr_modulesToSchools = o.tr_modulesToSchools,
            type = o.type
          }).ToList();
        newData[0].name = newData[0].name + "XYZ";
        newData[1].name = newData[1].name + "ABC";
        var contents = dc.tr_Content.ToList();

        foreach (var entryold in oldData)
        {
          foreach (var entrynew in newData)
          {
            if (entrynew.schoolUID == entryold.schoolUID && entrynew.name != entryold.name)
            {
              string filter = "-Courses- School " + entryold.name + " Banner Image";
              var schoolContents = contents.Where(p => p.Label.Contains(filter));
              foreach (var schoolContent in schoolContents)
              {
                schoolContent.Label = schoolContent.Label.Replace(entryold.name, entrynew.name);

              }
            }
          }
        }

        dc.SaveChanges();
```

what i am doing here is updating the label by finding the old label in database and replacing it with the new label.

My connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TrainingConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ABCD;User ID=***;Password=*****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="TrainingEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DAL.TrainingEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.DAL.TrainingEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.DAL.TrainingEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ABCD;user id=***;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this;

```
        dc.Entry(oldData).State = EntityState.Modified;
        dc.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
        dc.Entry(oldData).CurrentValues.SetValues(newData);
        dc.SaveChanges();
```